# ¿Cómo guardar los valores en un array?

Tags: c#

```
//+===================================================================
//
//   Acerca del programa : 
//   29. Matriz 4. Elaborar un programa que cree una matriz y 
//     que le muestre al usuario un menú con tres opciones: 1) Insertar un elemento  2) Imprimir matriz y  3) Salir del programa.   
//
//   Autor del codigo : Gilberto Quintero Armenta
//
// 
// 
//+===================================================================

using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {


        int opcion,cordenadaArray,valorArray;
        Console.WriteLine("Bienvenidos al programa 29");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");

        Console.WriteLine(" tres opciones: 1) Insertar un elemento  2) Imprimir matriz y  3) Salir del programa.");

        Console.WriteLine("Selecciona el numero:");
        string opcionapedir = Console.ReadLine();
        opcion = Convert.ToInt32(opcionapedir);
        /*
        Si el usuario selecciona la primera opción, el programa debe pedirle las coordenadas de una casilla en la matriz y un número entero que se insertará en la casilla que se haya determinado.
        */

       int[] myArr1 = new int[1];


      switch (opcion)
      {
          case 1:
           Console.WriteLine("Dame la cordenada donde quieres que se agrege el valor :"); 
           string cordenada = Console.ReadLine();
           cordenadaArray = Convert.ToInt32(cordenada);
          Console.WriteLine("Dame el valor para agregar en la cordenada anterior:");
          string valor =Console.ReadLine();
          valorArray = Convert.ToInt32(valor);
          myArr1.SetValue( valorArray, cordenadaArray );




          break;
          case 2:
        for (int i = 0; i < myArr1.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(myArr1[i] + " ");

            }

          break;
          default:
              Console.WriteLine("Default case");
              break;
      }     

    }

}
```

Estoy intentando guardas los valores solicitados por el usuario en un array y después imprimirlo, ¿alguien sabe cual podría ser mi error?

Como ven en esta línea:

```
myArr1.SetValue( valorArray, cordenadaArray);
```

Estoy intentando guardar los valores en el array "miArr1".

Comment: Revertí tu edición, pues hace que pierda sentido tu publicación y así mismo las respuestas dadas, por favor no lo hagas

Answer (score 0):

Definitivamente tu codigo deberia estar tirando un error. Para futuras publicaciones por favor aclaralo.

Para llengar el valor de un vector, solamente debes hacer:

```
myArr1[pos] = valor
```

Donde `pos` el la posicion del array que queres llenar, y `valor` el valor que quieres agregar en esa posicion. Recuerda que si es un array de objetos, debes inicializar el objeto que estas pasando usando `new` (sobre todo si queres obtener el valor del mismo sin setearlo previamente).

Comment: oh gracias por tu comentario ya me di una idea y  el problema es que no m e tiro ningun error solo se colgo y ahi se quedo y se cerro la consola y ya, p

Answer (score 0):

Tu error esta en que creas un array de tamaño fijo (1), deberias poner un tamaño mas grande y/o especificar al usuario que el valor de la coordenada debe estar dentro de los limites, por supesto tampoco puede ser una coordenada negativa, pues los arrays van de 0 al tamaño especificado

> int[] myArr1 = new int[5000];

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {


    int opcion,cordenadaArray,valorArray;
    Console.WriteLine("Bienvenidos al programa 29");
    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");

    Console.WriteLine(" tres opciones: 1) Insertar un elemento  2) Imprimir matriz y  3) Salir del programa.");

    Console.WriteLine("Selecciona el numero:");
    string opcionapedir = Console.ReadLine();
    opcion = Convert.ToInt32(opcionapedir);
    /*
    Si el usuario selecciona la primera opción, el programa debe pedirle las coordenadas 
    de una casilla en la matriz y un número entero que se insertará en la casilla que se haya determinado.
    */

   int[] myArr1 = new int[5000];


  switch (opcion)
  {
      case 1:
       Console.WriteLine("Dame la cordenada donde quieres que se agrege el valor :"); 
       string cordenada = Console.ReadLine();
       cordenadaArray = Convert.ToInt32(cordenada);
      Console.WriteLine("Dame el valor para agregar en la cordenada anterior:");
      string valor =Console.ReadLine();
      valorArray = Convert.ToInt32(valor);
      myArr1.SetValue( valorArray, cordenadaArray );




      break;
      case 2:
    for (int i = 0; i < myArr1.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(myArr1[i] + " ");

        }

      break;
      default:
          Console.WriteLine("Default case");
          break;
  }     

 }
}
```